# Dockerizing Laravel 4.1 Project with PHP 5.6 and MySQL 5.7.20

Tags: docker, laravel-4, php-5.6, laravel-config

Description:
I have an existing Laravel 4.1 project that requires PHP 5.6 and MySQL 5.7.20. My development environment is on Ubuntu 20.04 with PHP 8.1 and MySQL 8.0.35. I am looking to Dockerize this project to ensure a consistent development environment.

Requirements:
Use PHP 5.6 in the Docker container.
MySQL version 5.7.20 in the Docker container.
Set up the necessary configurations for Laravel 4.1.

Questions:
Dockerfile for PHP 5.6:
I need guidance on creating a Dockerfile that installs PHP 5.6 for my Laravel 4.1 project. What specific steps and commands should I include?

Dockerfile for MySQL 5.7.20:
Similarly, how can I create a Dockerfile for MySQL 5.7.20 to ensure compatibility with my Laravel 4.1 project? Any specific configurations or settings I need to be aware of?

Docker Compose:
What should my docker-compose.yml file look like to orchestrate both the PHP and MySQL containers? Are there any best practices or considerations for Laravel 4.1?

Laravel 4.1 Configuration:
Are there any specific Laravel configurations I need to adjust to work seamlessly with PHP 5.6 and MySQL 5.7.20 inside Docker?

Development Workflow:
How should I structure my Docker setup for an efficient development workflow? Are there any tools or practices I should adopt?

Additional Context:
I have already checked Docker Hub for PHP 5.6 and MySQL 5.7.20 images but would appreciate guidance on selecting the most appropriate ones for my scenario.
Any tips or recommendations for managing dependencies and environment variables within Docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This procedure is success for this project,

1. https://github.com/a2way-com/drop-in-docker-php  using this you can dockarize a laravel app easily.
2. have to change this to suitable way of this project, here I attached my changes.

App.Dockerfile

```
FROM php:5.6-fpm-alpine
ARG UID
RUN apk --update add shadow
RUN usermod -u $UID www-data && groupmod -g $UID www-data
RUN apk --update add sudo
RUN echo "www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
RUN apk add --no-cache libmcrypt-dev libmcrypt
RUN apk --update add composer
RUN docker-php-ext-install mcrypt
RUN docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN apk add --update npm
RUN apk add --update make
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
name: 'drop-in-docker-php'
services:
 mysql:
  image: mysql:5.7.44
  env_file:
   - ./env/mysql.env
  ports:
   - $MYSQL_PORT:3306
  volumes:
   - ./vols/mysql/:/var/lib/mysql/
  user: $UID:$UID
 adminer:
  image: adminer:4.8.1-standalone
  env_file:
   - ./env/adminer.env
  ports:
   - $ADMINER_PORT:8080
 mailhog:
  image: mailhog/mailhog:v1.0.1
  ports:
   - $MAILHOG_SMTP_PORT:1025
   - $MAILHOG_UI_PORT:8025
 app:
  image: $APP_IMAGE
  build:
   context: .
   dockerfile: ./Dockerfiles/app.Dockerfile
   args:
    UID: $UID
  volumes:
   - $APP_VOLUMES_SRC:/var/www/html/
   - ./vols/app/docker-user-home/:/home/www-data/
  env_file:
   - ./env/app.env
 static:
  image: nginx:1.24.0-alpine3.17
  volumes:
   - $STATIC_VOLUMES_PUBLIC:/usr/share/nginx/html/
 proxy:
  image: $PROXY_IMAGE
  build:
   context: .
   dockerfile: ./Dockerfiles/proxy.Dockerfile
  ports:
   - $PROXY_PORT:80
  env_file:
    - ./env/proxy.env
```

changing the above two files and making the env files correctly you can dockarize this project successfully.